# 2 different Facebook App IDs for one project - Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am creating 2 different apps (UrbanHero and UrbanHero Pro). Now I would like 2 different FACEBOOK sign ins (2 different Facebook App IDs) to be able to connect to my firebase real-time database.

Do I just separate the different App Ids and App Secrets with a comma or is it just not supported?

Thanks!

[image: firebase console]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Authentication only allows a single Facebook App ID for a single Firebase project. You'll either have to roll your own auth provider for the second app, or use a single Facebook App Id for both your apps. The latter is most common btw, so (unless you're already comfortable creating your own auth provider) I'd try that first.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will stick to one Facebook App ID.